# Cliente-Servidor, Threads, erro cliente ao ficar online

Tags: java, cliente-servidor

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação `cliente-servidor`, o servidor tem duas thread (uma `in` e outra `out`) bem implementadas.

Percorro o servidor (tudo bem), percorro o primeiro cliente e coloco como online (tudo bem), percorro  o segundo cliente e quando carrego no online ele fica bloqueado.

Tentei fazer um ciclo:

`for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)`

Notei com este ciclo que o primeiro cliente também bloqueia ao ficar online, ou seja, o erro do meu projecto está aqui! Alguém me consegue ajudar?

Segue o código:

```
public PainelEstadoContacto(JanelaUtilizador janelaUtilizador) {
    this.janelaUtilizador=janelaUtilizador;

    botaoOnline= new JButton("ONLINE");
    botaoOnline.addActionListener(e -> {
        String nome = nomeUtilizador.getText();

        if(!nome.isEmpty()){
            this.mensagem = new Mensagem();
            this.mensagem.setAccao(Accao.ONLINE);
            this.mensagem.setNomeClienteEnviaMensagem(nome);

            this.socketCliente = new SocketCliente();
            this.socket = this.socketCliente.estabelecerLigacao();          

            new Thread(new ThreadCliente(this.socket)).start();                              }
        this.socketCliente.enviar(mensagem);

    });
```

Comment: Ao fazer o loop, o primeiro também fica, mas não é porque outro tomou o lugar? Se houver o bloco synchronized, não vai continuar com apenas um de qualquer forma?

Comment: @DouglasGaldino sim tenho o bloco synchronized deveria de continuar com mais de um cliente é estranho